# How to exclude a source from those under source root?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, m2e, pom.xml

In my project's [pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) I have section responsible for generating sources:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                             ...
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources-myownp</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/MyOwnProj.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                 ...
```

It works well, except for one "*sourceRoot*" which happens to be duplicate as it is included in two difference packages.

Is there a way to specify an explicit "exclude" for that source package in [pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation usually you don't need to specify the sourceRoot. Excerpt from the [docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html):

> By default, the codegen plugin follows the Maven convention of
>   "target/generated-sources/cxf" for the output folder for the generated
>   classes. You can override this value using  as shown
>   below, but note this is usually not necessary

Maybe i misunderstand you problem.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining my problem clearly enough: I **do** want to specify the *sourceRoot*. But at the same time I want to exclude one subdirectory in that sourceRoot. Is that possible? +1 for trying to help.

Comment: I don't thinks so. Nor the docs say something like this. I'm not sure why you need to specify the sourceRoot folder cause this is the output of the generation process which makes in my opinion no sense?

Comment: I think you're right. I will have to study this a little more in depth.